# Trouble installing ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

Error in Eclipse:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: Android Development Tools
>   12.0.0.v201106281929-138431 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431)

Comment: you may try like download the ADT plugin manually, and then install it from locally.. this is the link for downloading http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-12.0.0.zip

Comment: thanks for the help, I didn't think it would be so hard to install. And it looks like lots of other people are having the same problems.

Comment: sometimes it is creating problems but not at all...this the alter way as i said to u

Comment: I downloaded it, added it to the available software sites and tried againg and got the same error. Oh well

Comment: not like that...dont add it to the websites, when you will click on add button it will ask for u to add a site and also for the local place if you have the plugin locally on your computer and at that time give the path to your directory where the you downloaded the ADT plugin. and then it will be done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conflicting dependency error means that you have installed some / all the packages for this Eclipse plugin (ADT is an Eclipse plugin) in the past and you are trying to install it again from different source (like from a downloaded file instead from the update urls).
All you have to do is:
**Delete the Plugin** - in eclipse, go to the upper application bar -> Help -> Install New Software.
Then, the Available Software will appear, and you will see at the bottom right corner a link named "What is already installed", click it.
When the Eclipse Installation Details window will appear, go to the "Installed Software" tab
and mark all the plugins under Android and select "Uninstall" button.
**Install the new one** - now you can install the plugin from whatever you choose (it's more recommended to install it via the given URL from Android installation tutorial) without encounting Conflicting dependency errors.

good day!